# Cumulative reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, reputation-graph

(Forgive me if this has been asked before, but I searched and couldn't find it.)

I think it would be neat to show a cumulative reputation graph on your profile to complement the daily reputation graph. Thoughts?

Comment: There was a cumulative reputation graph, but it has been replaced from the one shown in the network profile.

Comment: I like that this feature request is made by someone who looks like an integral sign. ;)

Comment: @ire_and_curses: I demand representation! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This exists, but it's on [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/12095/jtbandes) under the [reputation tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/12095/jtbandes?tab=reputation):

[image]

Comment: I don't see that one on my network profile. I see each of the individual site rep graphs, but not a cumulative one...

Comment: ahh - never mind. I meant cumulative in terms of sum of **all your rep from all sites**

Comment: Hey, that's even mine! :)  Thanks!

Comment: It only shows one of my accounts, not all of them. I don't have the option of  "top 5 accounts" or "all accounts." It only shows Stack Overflow.