# Please add cumulative reputation graph to profile

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cumulative reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125301/cumulative-reputation-graph)

Could you please add cumulative reputation graph to profile? I mean: x-axis - time, y-axis - reputation the user had at that time.

Sometimes it would be useful to see what was the reputation level of particular user in particular time (e.g. what was his reputation when he posted this answer or question). Also it would be interesting to see how your reputation growed through time. The scale of Y-axis would of course need to be changed according to particular time interval selected.

Comment: [Have you seen the graph in your network profile?](http://stackexchange.com/users/349130/tomas?tab=reputation)

Comment: @Yannis Thanks. It is really not very intuitive. The place for reputation was always in the site profile, this is breaking expectations. And furthermore, I cannot see graph for just one particular site - would be useful for sites with low reputation in the example below.

Comment: Why do you downvote? I think the cummulative reputation graph should be in per-site profile for the reasons I sketched above: 1) user intuition 2) see just one site reputation.

Comment: @Tomas `The place for reputation was always in the site profile` Says who? That graph has been there for as long as I remember, fact that you only found out about it today doesn't really mean it's out of place.

Comment: @Yannis - the network profile is quite a new feature (not older than 1 year).

Comment: Hey, I said "for as long as I remember", which for me is usually 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @Yannis Aha, OK :-) Typical IT brain - big CPU, low RAM. This renders your previous comment useless though :-) Must use external memory next time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This already exists. Here's yours:

[image: rep graph]

Go to your profile on Meta or any other site. Click Network Profile. Once there, click reputation.

Comment: The feature is rather "hidden", though, since it requires several clicks to get there and also going off the domain.

Comment: If you are already seeing your user profile, it requires just two clicks.

Comment: Thanks. It is really not very intuitive. The place for reputation was always in the site profile, this is breaking expectations. And furthermore, I cannot see graph for just one particular site - would be useful for sites with low reputation (e.g. Super User in this particular example).

Comment: @Tomas click and drag on the graph to zoom. For example click at about y=1k rep; x=Jul 11 and drag down to 0 rep and along to Oct 12 and you'll see your Super User journey more clearly. (After you choose the radio button so it is shown.)

Comment: Thanks @Kate, cool! I also find out I can switch off the other accounts by clicking them in the legend and it will zoom in the SuperUser reputation automatically! Super-Cool!!!